# Oracle PL/SQL Trigger: update/insert with where condition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Maybe it's quite easy but I don't get ahead. The table `B` contains two fields: `product_no   NUMBER` and `product VARCHAR2`. What the trigger should do is to insert a corresponding product description from `BP-table` in which you also have the fields `product_no` and `product`.
E.g. you enter 20 in `B.product_no` then it should be automatically entered the right product from `BP-Table`. Oracle version is 11g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER A.trigger_on_B
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
ON A.B FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  varProduct varchar(20);
BEGIN
  SELECT bp.report_info 
    into varProduct
    from  bp, 
          B
   where bp.product_no = B.product_no;

   insert into B (product) values(varProduct) ;
exception 
  when others then NULL;
END;/
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: it doesn't work . Error message: ERROR line 51, col 12, ending_line 51, ending_col 18, Found 'varchar', Expecting: .   -or-   (   -or-   RETURN  RETURNING   -or-   LOG   -or-   ;

Comment: why? I have to define the variable, or not? When I proceed with this trigger I get another error that trigger is 'invalid and failed re-validation'

Answer (score 0):

You can user pseudo records :new, :old, to make it work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER A.trigger_on_B
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
ON A.B FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  varProduct varchar(20);
BEGIN
  SELECT bp.report_info 
    into varProduct
    from  bp
   where bp.product_no = :new.product_no;

   insert into B (product) values(varProduct) ;
exception 
  when others then NULL;
END;
```

- Get rid of the line `when others then NULL;` this is unappropriated you can't hide any exceptions.
- Get rid of your triggers, it is hard to maintenance code with logic in triggers. For more information check [this article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-sep/o58asktom-101055.html)